# How can you set legal as the default printing size in an rdlc file?

Tags: c#, reportviewer, rdlc

I have a C#.NET reportviewer rdlc file that I want to print in legal size by default.  No matter what I do the print dialog always has the paper size set to letter.  Unless you change it to legal before printing the report is cut off.

Someone suggested setting the report size manually or changing units from cm to inches but it didn't seem to have an affect.   Any ideas?

This is the contents of my rdlc file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition">
  <Body>
    <ReportItems>
      <Subreport Name="LoadoutReport">
        <ReportName>LoadoutReport</ReportName>
        <Parameters>
          <Parameter Name="GroupingProperty">
            <Value>Grouping</Value>
          </Parameter>
          <Parameter Name="GroupingValue">
            <Value>1</Value>
          </Parameter>
        </Parameters>
        <Height>6.67396cm</Height>
        <Width>7.5cm</Width>
        <Style>
          <Border>
            <Style>Solid</Style>
          </Border>
          <RightBorder>
            <Color>Black</Color>
          </RightBorder>
        </Style>
      </Subreport>
      <Subreport Name="LoadoutReport2">
        <ReportName>LoadoutReport</ReportName>
        <Parameters>
          <Parameter Name="GroupingProperty">
            <Value>Grouping</Value>
          </Parameter>
          <Parameter Name="GroupingValue">
            <Value>1</Value>
          </Parameter>
        </Parameters>
        <Left>7.60583cm</Left>
        <Height>6.67396cm</Height>
        <Width>7.5cm</Width>
        <ZIndex>1</ZIndex>
        <Style>
          <Border>
            <Style>Solid</Style>
          </Border>
          <LeftBorder>
            <Color>Black</Color>
          </LeftBorder>
          <RightBorder>
            <Color>Black</Color>
          </RightBorder>
        </Style>
      </Subreport>
      <Subreport Name="LoadoutReport3">
        <ReportName>LoadoutReport</ReportName>
        <Parameters>
          <Parameter Name="GroupingProperty">
            <Value>Grouping</Value>
          </Parameter>
          <Parameter Name="GroupingValue">
            <Value>1</Value>
          </Parameter>
        </Parameters>
        <Left>15.21167cm</Left>
        <Height>6.67396cm</Height>
        <Width>7.5cm</Width>
        <ZIndex>2</ZIndex>
        <Style>
          <Border>
            <Style>Solid</Style>
          </Border>
          <LeftBorder>
            <Color>Black</Color>
          </LeftBorder>
        </Style>
      </Subreport>
    </ReportItems>
    <Height>2.62754in</Height>
    <Style />
  </Body>
  <Width>8.9416in</Width>
  <Page>
    <PageHeight>8.5in</PageHeight>
    <PageWidth>14in</PageWidth>
    <LeftMargin>0.5in</LeftMargin>
    <RightMargin>0.3937in</RightMargin>
    <TopMargin>1in</TopMargin>
    <BottomMargin>0.7874in</BottomMargin>
    <ColumnSpacing>0.05118in</ColumnSpacing>
    <Style />
  </Page>
  <rd:ReportID>f154f70e-de6e-4320-82c8-44d60995e61a</rd:ReportID>
  <rd:ReportUnitType>Inch</rd:ReportUnitType>
</Report>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the form load where your report viewer is located ....

---

```
using System.Drawing.Printing;
```

...

```
PageSettings ps = new PageSettings(); //Declare a new PageSettings for printing
ps.Landscape = false; //Set True for landscape, False for Portrait
ps.Margins = new Margins(0, 0, 0, 0); //Set margins
//Choose paper size from the paper sizes defined in ur printer.
//Here we use Linq to quickly choose by name
ps.PaperSize =
    (from PaperSize p
    in ps.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes
    where p.PaperName == "Legal" select p).First();
//Alternatively you can set the paper size as custom
//ps.PaperSize = new PaperSize("MyPaperSize", 100, 100);

reportViewer1.SetPageSettings(ps);
```